# Problems converting a csv file to flare.json

Tags: java, json, bash, csv, d3.js

I am not a programmer and new to Java.  I have searched for a method to convert csv to flare.json to use in D3.js data visualisations.  The simplest method was found here

https://github.com/albertchang/CSV-to-flare.json-D3-parser/blob/master/readme.md

I tried it but keep receiving an error message in the command line (terminal on Mac OS X El Capitan):

```
command not found.  Java and javac programmes all present and correct with recent versions.
```

Here is a [Screenshot of working directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5mWP.png) located in the D3_projects sub folder.

Here are the first few rows of the csv file

```
Type,CA1,CA2,CA3,CA4
Customer,Sales and Marketing,Marketing,Market Research,

Customer,Sales and Marketing,Marketing,Marketing Communications,
Customer,Sales and Marketing,Marketing,Pricing,
Customer,Sales and Marketing,Sales,Sales Planning and Forecasting,
Customer,Sales and Marketing,Sales,Customer Segmentation,
Customer,Sales and Marketing,Sales,Customer Acquisition,Opportunity Management
```

There is an empty flare.json file in the working directory (I also tried to run the programme without the empty file).

Below is a copy of what I added to terminal and the error messages

```
Last login: Thu Apr 21 19:40:19 on ttys000
You have mail.
Rics-MacBook-Pro:~ ric$ cd /Users/ric/Documents/D3_Projects
Rics-MacBook-Pro:D3_Projects ric$ $ javac -cp json-simple-1.1.1.jar D3Taxonomy.java $ java -cp json-simple-1.1.1.jar: D3Taxonomy taxonomy_CA.csv " , "
-bash: $: command not found
Rics-MacBook-Pro:D3_Projects ric$ $ javac -cp json-simple-1.1.1.jar D3Taxonomy.java $ java -cp json-simple-1.1.1.jar: D3Taxonomy CA.csv " , "
-bash: $: command not found
```

As you can see I have tried various permutations but keep getting the same error

```
$: command not found
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi, when you copy/paste the commands from that readme file, don't include the initial "$".  That "$" sign in the front just indicates that everything after it is a terminal command.

Comment: Thanks Seemant - that worked. Easy when you know how!

Comment: You're very welcome.  Here's a great intro about that sorta thing: https://github.com/INFO-474/m1-terminal-and-git

Answer (score 0):

Answered By **@Seemant Kulleen**

Just for this Q to close.

So the error was that when you copied the code you left the $ sign from the terminal inside the commands.